# How to continue program execution when using bufio.Scanner in golang

Tags: go, stdin

Forgive me I am starting out in Go and I am learning about the bufio package but every time I use the Scanner type the command line is stuck on the input and does not continue with normal program flow. I have tried pressing Enter but it just keeps going to a new line.

Here is my code.

```
/*
Dup 1 prints the text of each line that appears more than
once in the standard input, proceeded by its count.
*/
package main

import(
  "bufio"
  "fmt"
  "os"
)

func main(){
  counts := make(map[string]int)
  fmt.Println("Type Some Text")
  input := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

  for input.Scan(){
    counts[input.Text()]++
  }
  //NOTE: Ignoring potential Errors from  input.Err()

  for line,n := range counts{
    if n > 1{
      fmt.Printf("%d \t %s \n",n,line)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a `for` loop which reads lines from the standard input. This loop will run as long as `os.Stdin` doesn't report `io.EOF` (that's one case when `Scanner.Scan()` would return `false`). Normally this won't happen.

If you want to "simulate" the end of input, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on Windows, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on Linux / unix systems.

So enter some lines (each "closed" by <kbd>Enter</kbd>), and when you're finished, press the above mentioned key.

Example output:

```
Type Some Text
a
a
bb
bb 
bbb                               <-- CTRL+D pressed here
2        a 
2        bb
```

Another option would be to use a "special" word for termination, such as `"exit"`. It could look like this:

```
for input.Scan() {
    line := input.Text()
    if line == "exit" {
        break
    }
    counts[line]++
}
```

Testing it:

```
Type Some Text
a
a
bb
bb
bbb
exit
2        a 
2        bb
```